Progress Bar Inside Parallelized Loop?
I have this parallelized for loop and it takes awhile so I'd like to have a progress bar. I can't seem to get any of the 'typical,' txtProgressBar, or progress library bars to actually output anything when it's running inside the loop. What am I missing here?
results <- foreach(alpha_value = alpha_seq, .packages = c("glmnet")) %dopar% {
  # Set the seed for inside the parallel loop
  set.seed(1024)
  # Fit the elastic net model using cross-validation
  cv_model <- cv.glmnet(feature_vars, 
                        target_var,
                        nfolds = 3,
                        alpha = alpha_value, 
                        family = "gaussian")
  
  # Capture R-squared
  lambda_index <- which(cv_model$lambda == cv_model$lambda.1se)
  r_squared <- cv_model$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio[lambda_index]
  
  # Capture Mean Squared Error  
  mse <- ifelse(is.na(cv_model$cvm[cv_model$lambda == cv_model$lambda.1se]) | 
                  is.null(cv_model$cvm[cv_model$lambda == cv_model$lambda.1se]),
                NA, 
                cv_model$cvm[cv_model$lambda == cv_model$lambda.1se])
  
  # Return results for this iteration
  list(alpha_value = alpha_value, r_squared = r_squared, mse = mse)
}

I have tried txtProgressBar, and Progress library functions, I don't have any syntax errors and they work outside of the parallel version of the loop. I've looked at some other similar posts discussing Progressr but they don't seem to offer a solution.

The progressr package works with parallel processing if you use a Futureverse backend.  See https://progressr.futureverse.org/#foreach-with-dofuture for examples.
